# JRE System Library not displaying my correct java version

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium

I have Java 12.0.1 on my computer. I am not getting an Error for incompatible version. I am getting a warning.

Please note that I have tried all the below:

1) Checked Java version and maven version on my computer and it looks correctly configured

2) Clicked Maven > Update Project multiple times

3) Changed Java version in "source" and "target" in 'Maven Compiler Plug-in' to 12 (I even tried 12.0.1 but didn't work).

4) Looked at JRE files for Eclipse in Windows Preferences and it is showing the correct JDK

I need JRE System Library to display Java version 12. It is still displaying the default value of "J2SE-1.5"

Comment: What version of eclipse did you install?

Comment: You need Eclipse 2019-03 plus the Java 12 patch to make Eclipse recognise Java 12 (or wait for Eclipse 2019-06 released next month).